# Is there a way to solve Ternary first-order equation with Maxima?

Tags: linear-equation, wxmaxima

I want to know the Solving Syntax for Ternary first-order equation on maxima.

For example;

> F_A + F_C + F_E - 15 = 0;
>   -F_A *0.4  + 15*0.2 m + F_E*0.4 = 0; 
>   F_C = 0.3*F_A + 0.3*F_E;

wanna know How to get the solution F_A, F_C, F _E?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a system of linear equations, one can call `linsolve` to solve it.

```
(%i10) eq1: F_E + F_C + F_A - 15 = 0 $
(%i11) eq2: 3.0*m + 0.4*F_E - 0.4*F_A = 0 $
(%i12) eq3: F_C = 0.3*F_E + 0.3*F_A $
(%i13) linsolve ([eq1, eq2, eq3], [F_A, F_C, F_E]);

rat: replaced -0.4 by -2/5 = -0.4

rat: replaced 0.4 by 2/5 = 0.4

rat: replaced 3.0 by 3/1 = 3.0

rat: replaced -0.3 by -3/10 = -0.3

rat: replaced -0.3 by -3/10 = -0.3
              195*m + 300        45          195*m - 300
(%o13) [F_A = -----------, F_C = --, F_E = - -----------]
                  52             13              52
```

Note that it's not necessary for all terms to have a numerical value -- in the solution above, `m` is a free variable.

Note also that Maxima prefers exact numbers (i.e., integers and rational numbers) to inexact numbers (i.e., floating point). `linsolve` converts floats to rationals and then works with the result.

Answer (score -1):

Let those be =>

```
F_A = x; F_C = y; F_E = z;
x + y + z = 15
-0.4*x + 0.4*z = 3
0.3*x -y + 0.3*z = 0
```

On  Mathlab,
[refer to the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC8dv.gif)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18n-rt3S2Eir8bPECn3YmbI6KievQjUUZ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18l947K9B13hfMkEKh0GAeMLakBz11UKI/view?usp=drivesdk